# Add Filter to Vlookup formula Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I know verry little about formulas

I have a Vlookup formula which is working

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(ConnectionHelper!M2:M, ConnectionHelper!$D$2:$E, {2,1}, false)))
```

I want to FILTER out rows if a cell in column D is empty

But not getting how or ever if possible!

I am trying

```
=Filter(ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(ConnectionHelper!M2:M, ConnectionHelper!$D$2:$E, {2,1}, false))),D2:D<>'')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=query(ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(ConnectionHelper!M2:M, ConnectionHelper!$D$2:$E, {2,1}, false))), "where Col2 <>''")
```

(assuming your data in column D is text).