# Filter Vlookup results inside a query

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

the problem I am immediately trying to solve is filtering the results of a VLOOKUP.

This formula is working:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(vlookup($A$4:$A,importrange("1XYHLG4-BhVUxXObvjEiozI6i19H5Jum97g87uFS6sYs", "DO_NOT_USE!A2:H3000"),{2,3,4,5},false)))`

but I want to auto filter the results. I found an answer on this post: [Add Filter to Vlookup formula Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53508355/add-filter-to-vlookup-formula-google-sheets)

However, when I do that, it seems ignores the VLOOKUP part. My results are no longer matched to the correct index key in Col A.

`=query(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(vlookup(A4:A,importrange("1XYHLG4-BhVUxXObvjEiozI6i19H5Jum97g87uFS6sYs", "DO_NOT_USE!A2:H3000"),{2,3,4,5},false))), "WHERE Col2='"&B2&"'", 1)`

Additional context: The problem I was originally trying to solve for was linking dynamic and static data. I have a larger sheet that I have divided using a query so that each school (about 60 schools) is only allowed to see data that pertains to them. Unfortunately, they must be able to manually add info to that sheet (this data is eventually generated into yet another sheet and required). I started solving this problem because this entire process was always done entirely on paper before and all info was hand-entered.

I feel like I'm SO CLOSE to a solution but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

EDIT- Sample data:

[Fake Source Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zSivb83POAerrQAJpfu68HlWTLKtsLgBu-MKf-b3SBc/edit?usp=sharing)

[Fake Query Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16HUIbCb43PCGFU1gfaKPiSThX135tw2HcgWwkFRMqRc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share a sheet with the some sample data and the expected output? It will be easier to troubleshoot then.

Comment: @Broly I think that in creating some fake data I uncovered that maybe an additional step will be needed, but would still appreciate your expertise.       
 Fake source data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zSivb83POAerrQAJpfu68HlWTLKtsLgBu-MKf-b3SBc/edit?usp=sharing                                                                        
 Fake Outputs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16HUIbCb43PCGFU1gfaKPiSThX135tw2HcgWwkFRMqRc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem for not return result as per expectation is an issue of `Vlookup multiple criteria`, due to `query` will always filter all the data into a new table rather than try to create `row by row matching` and return blank row if not found:

1.To solve your issue with simple formula, first you need to add `Helper Column` in your source data:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B13&" "&C2:C13)
```

2.The revised source data:

[image]

3.Next, to use `Vlookup` with some modification (I didnot use `importrange` here because I am refering within same table)

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(vlookup($B$16:$B&" "&$G$15,$A$1:$I$13,{2,3,4,5},false)))
```

**The final outcome**

[image]

You can display the result using `query` function without plain text ID also, so that it will only return specific column and when the school is equal to the cell value:

```
=QUERY(B1:I13, "select B,C,D,E,F where C = '"&G15&"'")
```

[image]

Comment: I missed a whole step with the helper column. Thank you, that's working perfectly. As a final step, would there be anyway to then autofilter out the blank rows so that only School C appears on the sheet (all other index keys hidden)? I tried `Filter` so far with no luck.

Comment: Ya, I have edited my answer with extra query function, see if does work for your case :)

Comment: Thanks! I was originally using `query` but then encountered the static vs dynamic fields problem. I read that `vlookup` was the best solution, but at this point, I'm wondering if I am making this more complex than needed. Appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome, `query` can be dynamic also, I learn it recently :)